# Select rows with the most recent two dates based on value changes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table

| Date | Job_Id | Employee_ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | Teacher | 10 | Active |
| 2021-02-01 | Teacher | 10 | Active |
| 2021-03-01 | Teacher | 10 | Retired |
| 2021-04-01 | Teacher | 10 | Active |
| 2021-01-01 | Barber | 11 | Active |
| 2021-02-01 | Barber | 11 | Suspended |
| 2021-03-01 | Barber | 11 | Active |
| 2021-04-01 | Barber | 11 | Active |

and I would like a query to return this result set

| Date | Job_Id | Employee_ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | Teacher | 10 | Retired |
| 2021-04-01 | Teacher | 10 | Active |
| 2021-02-01 | Barber | 11 | Suspended |
| 2021-03-01 | Barber | 11 | Active |

Essentially, it should return the two most recent records when the status changed.
I'm currently experimenting with a lag function but I'm not too proficient at SQL yet and here's where I'm stuck.

```
SELECT Date, Job_ID,Employee_ID, [Status], PrevStatus FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
Date,
    Job_ID,
      Employee_ID,
      [Status],
      LAG([Status]) OVER (PARTITION BY Job_ID ORDER BY ExtractDate ) AS PrevStatus
FROM    #Statuses
) AS a
WHERE a.PrevStatus <> [Status] AND a.PrevStatus IS NOT NULL
```

Would anyone have any ideas on how to modify this?

Comment: isn't `Barber` `Employee_ID` = `11` ?

Comment: It is -- sorry I mocked up the data and made a mistake. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I guess you need `lag()` **and** `lead()` to get all rows where the status in the next **or** the previous row changes. You then need to use `row_number()` on that result to get the last two.

```
SELECT date,
       job_id,
       employee_id,
       status
       FROM (SELECT date,
                    job_id,
                    employee_id,
                    status,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id,
                                                    job_id
                                       ORDER BY date DESC) row_number
                    FROM (SELECT date,
                                 job_id,
                                 employee_id,
                                 status,
                                 lag(status, 1, status) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id,
                                                                           job_id
                                                              ORDER BY date ASC) prevstatus,
                                 lead(status, 1, status) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id,
                                                                            job_id
                                                               ORDER BY date ASC) nextstatus
                                 FROM elbat) x
                    WHERE status <> prevstatus
                           OR status <> nextstatus) y
            WHERE row_number <= 2
            ORDER BY employee_id ASC,
                     date ASC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f8793afe7dbaa8220a55737e572cda7a)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you wanted is the same as the last 2 unique status for each employee

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    select *, 
           rn = row_number() over (partition by Employee_ID, [Status]
                                       order by [Date] desc)
    from   #Statuses
) d
WHERE  d.rn = 1
order by Employee_ID, [Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, I don't understand the use case but why do you want to use LAG?

I would do something like this?

```
SELECT MAX(Date), Job_Id, Employee_ID, Status
FROM #Statuses
GROUP BY Job_ID, Employee_ID, Status
```

Comment: The idea is to get the rows with that were changed the most recent, despite not knowing when or if they were changed. I would only want to see job_ids, employee_ids, and statuses if a status actually changed some time in a given time period.